# Anyway to shorten my BigQuery script (for loop?)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Alright, I feel like I am missing something really basic. T.T

```
SELECT
    CATEGORY,
    PRODUCT,
    (CASE
         WHEN PRODUCT_DETAIL = 'STRAWBERRY' AND some_condition = x THEN 'REQUIRE REVIEW'
         WHEN PRODUCT_DETAIL = 'COD' AND some_condition = x THEN 'REQUIRE REVIEW'
         WHEN PRODUCT_DETAIL = 'MILK' AND some_condition = x THEN 'REQUIRE REVIEW'
         WHEN PRODUCT_DETAIL = 'BREAD' AND some_condition = x THEN 'REQUIRE REVIEW'
         ...
         WHEN PRODUCT_DETAIL = 'ICE CREAM' AND some_condition = x THEN 'REQUIRE REVIEW'
     ELSE 'GOOD'
     END) AS PRODUCT_CONDITION 

FROM
    MAIN_DATABASE
```

I suppose my question is since {AND some_condition = X THEN 'REQUIRE REVIEW'} is all the same, is there any way to shorten the code to some form of

```
    WHEN PRODUCT_DETAIL = ('STRAWBERRY', 'COD', 'MILK', ... , 'ICE CREAM') AND some_condition = x
    THEN 'REQUIRE REVIEW'
    ELSE 'GOOD'
```

or some variation of it?

Thanks, CN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `IN`:

```
(CASE WHEN PRODUCT_DETAIL IN ('STRAWBERRY' , 'COD', . . . ) AND
           some_condition = x
      THEN 'REQUIRE REVIEW'
      ELSE 'GOOD'
 END) AS PRODUCT_CONDITION
```